# how do i split multiple lines of data in one cell in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I receive this data in one cell as an export from TV.  I need to split this data so that it appears in individual rows.  I would prefer to do this via VBA and not formulas as I need it manipulated automatically without much human intervention.   Does anyone know how I can do this?  Text to Columns does not work for this example unfortunately.

[image]

The top 2 lines BINANCE:USDT PAIRS AND Oversold need to be on the lines with the Gala and ICP.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

### Split Multi-Line Cell to Another Worksheet

- Adjust the values in the constants section.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub SplitCoins()
   
    ' Source
    Const sName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const sfCellAddress As String = "A2"
    Const sDelimiter As String = vbLf ' maybe 'vbCrLf'?
    ' Destination
    Const dName As String = "Sheet2"
    Const dfCellAddress As String = "A2"
    Const dcCount As Long = 7
    Const dhCount As Long = 2
    ' Workbook
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Worksheets(sName)
    If sws.AutoFilterMode Then sws.AutoFilterMode = False
    Dim sData As Variant
    sData = GetColumnRange(RefColumn(sws.Range(sfCellAddress)))
    Dim srCount As Long: srCount = UBound(sData, 1)
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Worksheets(dName)
    Dim dCell As Range: Set dCell = dws.Range(dfCellAddress)
    
    Dim drCount As Long
    Dim sr As Long
    Dim dr As Long
    Dim c As Long
    
    Dim sSubStrings() As String
    Dim h67SubStrings() As String
    
    Dim sString As String
    Dim h1String As String
    Dim h3String As String
    Dim hcString As String
    Dim hbString As String
    Dim huString As String
    Dim h6String As String
    Dim h7string As String
    
    For sr = 1 To srCount
        sString = CStr(sData(sr, 1))
        If Len(sString) > 0 Then
            sSubStrings = Split(sString, sDelimiter)
            drCount = UBound(sSubStrings) - LBound(sSubStrings) - dhCount + 1
            ReDim dData(1 To drCount, 1 To dcCount)
            dr = 0
            For c = 2 To UBound(sSubStrings)
                dr = dr + 1
                h1String = sSubStrings(0)
                dData(dr, 1) = h1String
                h3String = sSubStrings(c)
                hcString = Left(h3String, InStr(1, h3String, " ") - 1)
                dData(dr, 2) = hcString
                hbString = Left(h1String, InStr(1, h1String, ":"))
                huString = Split(Right(h1String, Len(h1String) _
                    - Len(hbString)), " ")(0)
                dData(dr, 3) = huString
                dData(dr, 4) = hbString & hcString & huString
                dData(dr, 5) = sSubStrings(1)
                h67SubStrings = Split(h3String, " ")
                dData(dr, 6) = Round(Split(h67SubStrings(1), ":")(1), 0)
                dData(dr, 7) = Round(Split(h67SubStrings(2), ":")(1), 0)
                ' If your decimal separator is a comma then use:
                'dData(dr, 6) = Round(Replace(Split(h67SubStrings(1), ":")(1), _
                    ".", ","), 0)
                'dData(dr, 7) = Round(Replace(Split(h67SubStrings(2), ":")(1), _
                    ".", ","), 0)
            Next c
            dCell.Resize(drCount, dcCount).Value = dData
            Set dCell = dCell.Offset(drCount)
            Erase dData
        End If
    Next sr

    MsgBox "Data split.", vbInformation

End Sub


''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Writes the values from a column ('ColumnNumber')
'               of a range ('rg') to a 2D one-based one-column array.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function GetColumnRange( _
    ByVal rg As Range, _
    Optional ByVal ColumnNumber As Long = 1) _
As Variant
    If rg Is Nothing Then Exit Function
    If ColumnNumber < 1 Then Exit Function
    If ColumnNumber > rg.Columns.Count Then Exit Function
    
    With rg.Columns(ColumnNumber)
        If rg.Rows.Count = 1 Then
            Dim Data As Variant: ReDim Data(1 To 1, 1 To 1): Data(1, 1) = .Value
            GetColumnRange = Data
        Else
            GetColumnRange = .Value
        End If
    End With

End Function


''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Creates a reference to the one-column range from the first cell
'               of a range ('FirstCell') to the bottom-most non-empty cell
'               of the first cell's worksheet column.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function RefColumn( _
    ByVal FirstCell As Range) _
As Range
    If FirstCell Is Nothing Then Exit Function
    
    With FirstCell.Cells(1)
        Dim lCell As Range
        Set lCell = .Resize(.Worksheet.Rows.Count - .Row + 1) _
            .Find("*", , xlFormulas, , , xlPrevious)
        If lCell Is Nothing Then Exit Function
        Set RefColumn = .Resize(lCell.Row - .Row + 1)
    End With

End Function
```

Comment: Thank you for sending me this. I added it to my excel and I am getting a run time error "5":  Invalid procedure call or argument.  When I click debug, it highlights this code in yellow:  hcString = Left(h3String, InStr(1, h3String, " ") - 1)

Comment: That's the one returning the left part before the first space in any row greater than row 2 i.e. `GALA` and `ICF`. If there is no space, it will fail. It will also fail if there is a leading space or invisible character. A long shot, but maybe you can fix it with `h3String = Trim(sSubStrings(c))`.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. It gave me this error run time error 9 on this line dData(dr, 6) = Round(Split(h67SubStrings(1), ":")(1), 0)

Comment: If you look two lines below, you will see that there is an out-commented version of the line when your decimal separator is a comma. Is it a comma? If not, you could try just `Split(h67SubStrings(1), ":")(1)` for starters and build on that.

Comment: there are no commas. so that didn't work either.

Comment: When it fails, what is the exact value of `h3String`? Just hover over the variable and it will show the value in a second or so.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240260/discussion-between-mgoblue33-and-vbasic2008).